# Forçar keydown Javascript em input autocomplete Google Maps!

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Pessoal tenho o seguinte problema preciso que ao clicar "Enter" em um input com auto complete do Google Maps, em seguida ele pressione a tecla para baixo para selecionar uma opção do Google Maps.. tentei de diversas formas mais não deu certo! tenho o seguinte código:

```
jQuery('.find-by__autocomplete').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.which = 40;
        jQuery(".find-by__autocomplete").trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Ele fica dentro do iframe ? Se for o navegador não permite que você simule um click ou qualquer trigger de teclado em uma pagina de fora do seu dominio

Comment: Não, ele é um input normal na página só está utilizando o autocomplete do google maps

Comment: Coloque essa parte do codigo junto na pergunta, o de html

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido da seguinte forma!

```js
jQuery("#autocomplete").keypress(function (e) {
    e.cancelBubble = true;

    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 9) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(e.target, "keydown", {
            keyCode: 40,
            hasRanOnce: true
        });

        google.maps.event.trigger(e.target, "keydown", {
            keyCode: 13,
            hasRanOnce: true
        });
    }
});
```